# Attribute error with find and findall in webscrape for urls

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, attributes

I'm a total beginner in python, so go easy on me. I am trying to scrape a website for links to success stories from customers. I am able to get all the links, but with additional ones I don't want or need like the company facebook or linkedin. I'm trying to get just the ones I want without those extra ones. I can pull them all up but once I try to narrow down my search further I keep getting the error: website = href attribute error, AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? I've tried using .find but I get the exact same error. This is the code I have so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests
req = Request('https://www.calix.com/about-calix/success-stories.html', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")
#mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "tabBlock noBackground"})
#print(mydivs)
links =soup.findAll('a', {"link black cta-js"})
#print(links)
website = links.('href')
print(website)
```

Comment: are you looking for company website ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for company websites then try this snippet

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests
req = Request('https://www.calix.com/about-calix/success-stories.html', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "tabBlock noBackground"})
# print(mydivs)
links =soup.findAll('a', {"class":"link black cta-js "})
for link in links:
  print(link['href']) #prints websites
```

as findAll returns a list you'll need to loop to get all links and
what you missed was a space character in the end of class `"link black cta-js "`

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I needed!